# How to group table and caption in Word 2011?

Tags: ms-office

I'm trying to create a load of tables with captions in Mac Word 2011, interspersed with figures, text, ect. With all the insertions, there's a lot of adjusting of where things go. But when I move the tables around, the captions stay put, and I don't see any way to group tables to keep their captions with them. Is there a way to make sure a table and its caption move together in Word 2011?

Just to be clear, I'm not asking how to make sure they stay together [over a page break](http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=66477) - I'd like to be able to move the table myself and have the caption come with it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a really difficult time with this. The only thing I found that was easy to do and effective was to add another row under the table, merge the columns of that row and format colour, lines accordingly, and then write the text I wanted as though it were a caption. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks - this won't work for me, though, unfortunately. I need to have regular captions that I can cross-reference, use for an easy table of contents, etc.

Comment: Just an untried idea, create a one-cell table; Place your real table inside the one-cell table; Move the one-cell table.